# Is there a solution to this problem?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, functions

I have been thinking about this for some time, but haven't hit upon anything yet. Any help will be appreciated.

Is there a function mapping $\mathbf R$ into $\mathbf R$  satisfying the following: It is entirely differentiable on the real line, everywhere positive and its derivative decreases as $x$ (the argument) increases.

If it is impossible, why?

I have mostly just tried to think of combinations of functions I know, but without luck. Also, I tried to show its impossibility, but have come up with nothing so far.

Comment: What kind of endomorphism is the function? Which properties are preserved?

Comment: @Allawonder what do you mean by "endomorphism"?  This could have several different meanings depending on what type of structure you care about.  (a mere self-map, or preserving addition, or preserving multiplication, etc)

Comment: @Randall Sorry, everybody. I asked this question late last night here and was tired and impatient to type in MathJax (slower than normal typing on the phone), so I was slack. I shall now edit to be as clear as possible.

Comment: @JohnDouma The simplest type. I was using it to mean "real-valued function of a single real variable." I have now edited the question.

Comment: @Gibbs Sorry for causing confusion with the 'endomorphism' part. I simply meant that $f:\mathbf R \to \mathbf R.$ Question now edited accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, such a function does not exist!

To see this, we show that any differentiable $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $f'$ (strictly) decreasing on all of $\mathbb{R}$ cannot be entirely positive. So let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable and $f'$ be decreasing. Start by noting that since $f'$ is decreasing, we may take $f'(0) \neq 0$ (by translating $f$ if necessary). Now, if $f'(0) < 0$, then at $k = - 2\frac{f(0)}{f'(0)}$, the fact that $f'$ is decreasing shows that $$f(k) = f(0) + \int_0^k{f'(t)}dt < f(0) + kf'(0) = f(0) - 2f(0) \leq 0.$$ Similarly, if $f'(0) \geq 0$, we can apply a symmetric argument to find a value $k < 0$ with $f(k) < 0$. This completes our proof.

Comment: Thanks. I smelt MVT too, but didn't know how to wield it.

Comment: Question:  does any of this assume that $f'$ is continuous?

Answer (score 2):

No such function exists, unless you allow non-strictly decreasing derivative and thereby accept constant functions.

If a differentiable function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ has a decreasing derivative, then $f'(x)$, being monotonic, either approaches a constant or $\pm \infty$ as $x \to \pm \infty$. If $f$ is to be everywhere positive, the $x \to - \infty$ limit of $f'(x)$ must be non-positive, while the $x \to \infty$ limit of $f'(x)$ must be non-negative, so the derivative cannot be decreasing unless it is identically zero.

Comment: This is a compelling picture!